# Firebase keeps removing all entries instead for only the specific one

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I simply cannot remove the specific entry from my Firebase:
[Picture of the Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McIzF.png)

It always removes the whole database.

I have tried those codes:

```
fun removeLobbyFromDatabase() {
    // lobbyId is string value of the key
    val query = db.child(lobbyId)

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.ref.removeValue()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}
```

and

```
fun removeLobbyFromDatabase() {
    val ref = db.ref
    ref.child(lobbyId).removeValue()
}
```

also (but nothing happens then)

```
fun removeLobbyFromDatabase() {
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.children.forEach { lobby -> if (lobby.key == lobbyId) lobby.ref.removeValue() }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}
```

Where **db** comes from here (I am using Dagger 2):

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getFirebaseRef(): DatabaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("lobbies")
```

How can I **only** remove the lobby (entry) and not whole database?

**>>> EDIT, SOLVED <<<**

This is very embarrasing to tell, but I noticed in the debugger that **lobbyId** was empty. Then I realized I cleared that String somewhere else. I was way too confident about that. Thanks to people for giving effort here anyway and this code worked perfectly well after solving my mistake:

```
fun removeLobbyFromDatabase() = db.child(lobbyId).removeValue()
```

So, if you are reading here and have the same problem, make sure to debug!

Comment: What is the value of `lobbyId`?

Comment: Constant String value of the key, in this case, example: "-LghCdSV-5HWF-tqoqiy"

Comment: So your solution is exactly my answer, right?

Comment: Heh, yep. This taught me a lesson - always debug even if you are 100% sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete an item from a Firebase realtime database, there is no need to attach a listener, you can simply call `removeValue()` function directly on the reference like this:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val lobbyIdRef = rootRef.child("lobbies").child("-LghCdSV-5HWF-tqoqiy")
lobbyIdRef.removeValue()
```

You can also use a [addOnCompleteListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)) to see when the remove operation is completed.